# String as foreign key - cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, relational-database

I have an `ApplicationUser` and a `Group`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    // ... some more properties
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GroupAdminId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser GroupAdmin { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> GroupUsers { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that a group has one admin-user and many ordinary users. Also, an `ApplicationUser` can only be a member of one `Group`, either as an admin or an ordinary user.

The PK for `ApplicationUser` is of type `string` (Guid).

I'm trying to define the relationships in `OnModelCreating()`, but I'm not doing it right:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasOne(a => a.GroupAdmin)
    .WithOne(g => g.Group)
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.GroupAdminId);
```

`.HasForeignKey(a => a.GroupAdminId)` causes this error:

> Error CS1660  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasMany(u => u.GroupUsers)
    .WithOne(g => g.Group);
```

The configuration for `GroupUsers` doesn't show any errors, but since the `GroupAdmin`-part isn't working, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand this stuff all too well, but I read a little bit [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration), and experimented a bit, and this seems to work:

I modified the `ApplicationUser` model to diffrenciate between admin and user relationship to a `Group`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int? AdminInGroupId { get; set; }
    public int? UserInGroupId { get; set; }
    public Group AdminInGroup { get; set; }
    public Group UserInGroup { get; set; }
}
```

`OnModelCreating()` configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasOne(a => a.GroupAdmin)
    .WithOne(g => g.AdminInGroup)
    .HasForeignKey<ApplicationUser>(a => a.AdminInGroupId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasMany(u => u.GroupUsers)
    .WithOne(g => g.UserInGroup)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```